# Sytanx errors: Create Batch Class to Process Stagings and insert Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I am working on a task. To understand my issue let me describe what I am doing.

---

Object:  staging__c

Fields:

Individual_or_Organization__c (Text)

Orgganization_Name__c

First_Name__c

Last_Name__c

Postal_Code__c

Date_Recieved__c (Date)

Amount__c (Currency)

Error_Message__c (Long Text)

Description__c

Requirement:

**Case1.  If  Individual_or_Organization__c==I**  ,

Search for existing contact with matching FistName , LastName and Postal Code. If contact not found then create new contact.

If staging record contains value in Orgganization_Name__c  and Postal_Code__c Fields then search for account with matching name and postal code. If account found then link contact record with this account.

Create new opportunity record for that contact

Case2. If  Individual_or_Organization__c==O

Search for existing Account  with matching  Orgganization_Name__c and Postal Code. If Account not found then create new account.

If staging record contains value in Last_Name__c and Postal_Code__c  Fields then search for contact with matching firstname,lastname  and postal code. If contact found then link contact record with the  account.

Create Opportunity record for account

Field Mapping for Opportunity:

OpportunityName = Account Name or Contact Name+CloseDate

CloseDate = Date_Recieved__c

Amount = Amount__C

Description=Description__c

---

**As you saw the requirement I am working on "condition 1" I wrote a batch class for same but still it raising few errors please have a look at my code**

```
global class BatchAssignment implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){     
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Individual_or_Organization__c,Orgganization_Name__c,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Postal_Code__c,Date_Recieved__c,Amount__c,Error_Message__c,Description__c 
                                         FROM staging__c]);
    }    
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<staging__c> scope){
        List<Opportunity> newOpptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
        if(scope != null && scope.Individual_or_Organization__c == 'I') {
            Account objAccount = searchAccount(scope);
            if(objAccount != null) {
                List<Contact> linkContactList = searchContact(objAccount, scope);
                try{
                    if(linkContactList != null && !linkContactList.isEmpty()) {
                        upsert linkContactList;
                        
                        //Create new opportunity;
                        for(Contact objCon : linkContactList) {
                            newOpptyList.add(new Opportunity(Name = objCon.FullName,
                                                             StageName = 'Prospecting',
                                                             AccountId = objAccount.Id,
                                                             ContactId = objCon.Id
                                                            ));                         //Add other required fields if needed.
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(newOpptyList != null && !newOpptyList.isEmpty()) {
                            insert newOpptyList;
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    system.debug('---Exception--' + ex);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    private Account searchAccount(staging__c scope) {
        if(scope.Orgganization_Name__c != null && scope.Postal_Code__c != null) {
            return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :scope.Orgganization_Name__c AND BillingPostalCode = :scope.Postal_Code__c];
            //Assuming here, there will be only one account with these combination in your system
        }
    }
    
    
    private List<Contact> searchContact(Account objAccount, staging__c scope) {
        List<Contact> linkContactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(scope.First_Name__c != null && scope.Last_Name__c != null && scope.Postal_Code__c != null) {
            List<Contact> existingContactList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact 
                                                 WHERE FirstName = :scope.First_Name__c AND LastName = :scope.Last_Name__c AND MailingPostalCode = :scope.Postal_Code__c];
            //For existing contacts
            if(existingContactList != null) {
                for(Contact objCon : existingContactList) {
                    objCon.AccountId = objAccount.Id;
                    linkContactList.add(objCon);
                }
            } else {
                //create new contact
                linkContactList.add(new Contact(FirstName = scope.First_Name__c, 
                                                LastName = scope.Last_Name__c,
                                                MailingPostalCode = scope.Postal_Code__c
                                                AccountId = objAccount.Id));
            }
            
        }
        return linkContactList;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
    }
```

**These are the errors I am unable to fix**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many errors in the code such that you are not looping the scope in the execute method, there were some issues regarding the open and close braces  `{` and `}` and also `,`.  I have updated the code now i don't see any errors.

```
global class BatchAssignment implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){     
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Individual_or_organization__c ,Orgganization_Name__c,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Postal_Code__c,Date_Recieved__c,Amount__c,Error_Message__c,Description__c 
                                         FROM staging__c]);
    }    
    
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<staging__c> scope){
        List<Opportunity> newOpptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
      for(staging__c sc:scope){
        if(sc != null && sc.Individual_or_organization__c  == 'I') {
            Account objAccount = searchAccount(sc);
            if(objAccount != null) {
                List<Contact> linkContactList = searchContact(objAccount, sc);
                system.debug('contact'+linkContactList);
                try{
                    if(linkContactList != null && !linkContactList.isEmpty()) {
                        upsert linkContactList;
                        
                        //Create new opportunity;
                        for(Contact objCon : linkContactList) {
                            newOpptyList.add(new Opportunity(Name = objCon.LastName,
                                                             StageName = 'Prospecting',
                                                             AccountId = objAccount.Id,
                                                             ContactId = objCon.Id,
                                                             CLOSEDATE=Date.today()
                                                            ));                         //Add other required fields if needed.
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(newOpptyList != null && !newOpptyList.isEmpty()) {
                            insert newOpptyList;
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    system.debug('---Exception--' + ex);
                }
                
            }
        }
      }
    }
    
    private Account searchAccount(staging__c scope) {
        Account acc= new Account();
        if(scope.Orgganization_Name__c != null && scope.Postal_Code__c != null) {
            acc= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :scope.Orgganization_Name__c AND BillingPostalCode = :scope.Postal_Code__c];
            //Assuming here, there will be only one account with these combination in your system
        }
        return acc;
    }
    
    
    private List<Contact> searchContact(Account objAccount, staging__c scope) {
        List<Contact> linkContactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(scope.First_Name__c != null && scope.Last_Name__c != null && scope.Postal_Code__c != null) {
            List<Contact> existingContactList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact 
                                                 WHERE FirstName = :scope.First_Name__c AND LastName = :scope.Last_Name__c AND MailingPostalCode = :scope.Postal_Code__c];
            //For existing contacts
            system.debug('existing contact'+existingContactList);
            if(existingContactList.size()>0 ) {
                for(Contact objCon : existingContactList) {
                    objCon.AccountId = objAccount.Id;
                    linkContactList.add(objCon);
                }
            } else {
                //create new contact
                system.debug('into else');
                linkContactList.add(new Contact(FirstName = scope.First_Name__c, 
                                                LastName = scope.Last_Name__c,
                                                MailingPostalCode = scope.Postal_Code__c,
                                                AccountId = objAccount.Id));
                system.debug('linked contact2'+linkContactList);
            }
            
        }
        return linkContactList;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
    }
}
```

Please find the below articles for best practices of batch apex and implementation as well.

[Batch apex Article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much I appreciate your help, I'll learn more from this documentation  link you provide :)

Comment: hi, I notice one thing your solution is using soql inside for loop. Can't we exclude soql from the loop? Because I heard It's a bad practice :/

Comment: Yes we can do it using aggregate updates by using set and Map

Answer (score 1):

There are few compilation issue I see right from your code above.

1. I see no closing curly braces at the end of the file.
2. In Method `searchAccount` and `searchContact` params are list but your are expecting Single object while declaring the method.
3. Method `searchAccount` does not have any return statement in else as the first return statement is inside `if` block.
4. In method `searchContact` while adding it to `linkContactList` you missed a comma `,` after this `scope.Postal_Code__c`

I may have not identified more minutely, but
These all are compilation issues which can be fixed from your end.